# Android Studio: Could not find method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to build my project in Android Studio. I had it working on an earlier setup of Android Studio, but in my new environment I am getting the following error:

```
> ERROR: Could not find method androidTestImplementation() for arguments
> [com.android.support.test.espresso`:espresso`-core:2.2.2,
> build_10ngq9uijdpe3fhr06db8r1me$_run_closure3$_closure11@673c3997] on
> object of type
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
> Open File
```

Here is the contents of build.gradle(module:app):

[image: Build.gradle]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Pasting an error is not a good title. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it. Thank you!

Comment: What else can I write from the error? edit: is good?

Comment: post your build gradle file showing what dependencies you have used

Comment: i can't add too long by 1350 characters maybe SS https://prnt.sc/ma1b9d

Comment: add `google()` to your project level gradle dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You have a compile typo.

This:

```
androidTestImplementation('', {
    exclude group: '', module: ''
})
```

Should be this:

```
androidTestImplementation('') {
    exclude group: '', module: ''
}
```

[Gradle Reference](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-exclude-specific-transitive-dependencies-of-something-i-depend-on/17991)

Comment: Thank you so much. but not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced parens/braces.

The syntax is like

```
androidTestImplementation("foo") { bar }
```

and not like

```
androidTestImplementation("foo", { bar })
```

Comment: Thank you so much. but not working